# JS - use preventDefault instead of return false

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not great with Js so looking for some help with some existing code.
I have the following anchor

```
<a href="#" class="addroom" onclick="return false;"><span>Add</span></a>
```

I am getting a warning regarding the 'onclick' event where its telling me that i dont have keyboard equivilant handler for the the onclick="return false; I have done some research and i can prevent this warning by using preventDefault. if i put this in a script tag in the page then it works the same and i think it will get rid of the issue.

```
$("a.addrom").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
```

});

However, i would prefer to add it to the existing js but im having a hard time working out whats going on. I am trying to add it to the click event.

```
setupRooms: function (settings) {
            //hide all age fields
            $(settings.agesSelector, settings.hotelSearchDiv).hide();
            //hide all except first
            $(settings.roomsSelector + ":not(:first)", settings.hotelSearchDiv).hide();
            $('select', settings.hotelSearchDiv).prop('selectedIndex', 0); //set all to 0
            $(settings.addRoomSelector, settings.hotelSearchDiv).on('click', function () {
                methods.addRoom(settings);
            });
            $(settings.removeRoomSelector, settings.hotelSearchDiv).on('click', function () {
                var id = $(this).data('id');
                methods.removeLastRoom(settings, id);
            });

            $(settings.childrenNumberSelector, settings.hotelSearchDiv).on('change', function () {
                methods.handleChildrenChange(settings, $(this));
            });
        },
```

Edit* This code worked for me thanks to @patrick & @roberto

```
        $(settings.addRoomSelector, settings.hotelSearchDiv).on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            methods.addRoom(settings);
        });
```

Comment: `class` is missing a closing `"`".

Comment: _" I am trying to add it to the click event."_ then add a parameter to your function and then add the preventDefault call inside the function just like you have in the second code snippet

Comment: missing " was a typo sorry. its actually ok in my code. can provide and example please patrick.

Comment: What is the part after the **edit** about? Is it something that does not work? Is it a solution?

Comment: Updated - thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Paul answering the question within the question is bad practice especially if it is not marked as such. An answer always belongs in the answer section. If your solution differs to the already given one then you can always create an own answer if you think it is worth to mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood correctly you want to add that on your click handlers:

```
$(settings.addRoomSelector, settings.hotelSearchDiv).on('click', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     methods.addRoom(settings);
});
$(settings.removeRoomSelector, settings.hotelSearchDiv).on('click', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var id = $(this).data('id');
     methods.removeLastRoom(settings, id);
});
```

Should be enough for having the prevent default in your click handlers.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks - just come to this conclusion following patricks comment. i updated my question just as you answered. Thanks @Roberto